# Replacing Values in R with Latency Values

Tags: r

@BenBolker Here is an example of the output I would like; I have no idea if it can even be done.

```
CURRENT_FIX_START   CURRENT_FIX_END identifier  trialtype   rotatedimaged
  targetloc prefix  corrfix errfix


7   202 30  rotated stimN11of2.jpg  left    231 254 0
7   208 42  rotated stimN221of2.jpg left    451 245 0
241 761 78  rotated stimW131-of2.jpg right  345 345 0
```

For each trial, where there is a correct prefix, denoted by having a time stamp, and a correct corrfix, I would want the script to print everything on the same line (I need to to get a latency measure from prefix to corrfix). Within the old data, the time stamps occurred on different lines. I was thinking about doing this manually, but it would be far too time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but how about:

```
latency <- with(mydata,abs(CURRENT_FIX_START-CURRENT_FIX_END))
for (i in c("prefix","corrfix","errfix")) {
   mydata[[i]] <- ifelse(mydata[[i]]==1,latency,0)
}
```

Comment: How hard would it would be to replace all the 0's in each of the columns, leaving only the time stamp for each trial? In each column there would be a numerical value for prefix and corrfix for each trial. I think there would be a mismatch of length if I did this, however.

Comment: To be more specific mydata[mydata$prefix!=0 & mydata$corrfix!=0,  1:18) will match the values, however,  the corrfix is returned on a different line and is a different value. I do not know how I can get values returned on a different line within the same trial.  So, for one line of data it would give me the time for prefix and the time for corrfix, for each trial.

Comment: can you offer any insights on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: not sure/don't have time at the moment.  Can you edit your question to (1) remove extraneous information (i.e. get rid of columns that don't enter into the question, although you can leave one if you want to indicate that extraneous columns should be carried along) and (2) gives a worked example of what you would like as output?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust for appropriate indexing, but this seems to work:

```
#fake data
dat <- data.frame(fix1 = runif(10), fix2 = runif(10), prefix = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                  corfix = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), errfix = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE))

dat[, 3:5] <- apply(dat[, 3:5], 2, function(x) ifelse(x == 1, abs(dat$fix1 - dat$fix2),x))
```